# POM file details

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, pom.xml

I am trying to redo the old sonarqube scan on a new sonarqube server.But when I tried to run the scan by taking a particular `commitid` (this is from the date 2015)from the bit bucket it shows an error on the jenkins:

```
POM file ilmanager-build\pom.xml specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist 
14:08:53 Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
14:08:53 Deleting 1 temporary files
14:08:54 Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help me figure out where to find the pom path of that time or some way to fix this one.

Thankyou.

Comment: You specifying wrong path to the `pom.xml`.

Comment: i had placed the path of pom.xml of which the project is using currently.But i am running it on the branch/commitid which was created in 2015 and how to know the pom.xml path of that branch that was used at that time..??@wilx

Comment: Easy, you checkout the branch at that point in time.